# Symfony - sfGuardPlugin - Registration

Tags: forms, registration, sfguard

I'm new in Symfony community so sorry if I'm asking about the topic which was already discussed.
I'm trying to use sfGuardPlugin in my project. Everything seems to be ok. The problem is that I don't really know how to easy implement registration engine. Does anybody know how to do it fast and easy ?

Is there is any plugin similar to sfGuardPlugin which is easy to use and has this method implemented ?

Please help.
Krzycho.

Answer (score 1):

[sfDoctrineApplyPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineApplyPlugin/1_1_1) or [sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin/1_5_6)

Comment: sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin greate plugin. Thanks denys281!